# Normal Reaction and Punctures

Tags: pressure

I'm curious on how, if every object creates a normal contact force equal to the force being put on it, seemingly preventing deformation or snapping of an object, how do objects break or how are they punctured?

Is there a maximum pressure (and therefore force, and therefore normal reaction) that objects have? If so, how is this calculated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the standard contact force named the "normal" is only used when the contact forces are small enough not to disturb the rigidity of the object. So basically it is used in mechanics when the conditions allow an object to be treated a rigid. But this is an idealization. If the force is strong enough it can alter the position of the atoms relative to each other, resulting in a deformed or cracked object. The particular force strength (or rather, pressure is the important variable here) needed depends on the particular material and there is no simple way to calculate it (it is easy to measure it though).

Comment: This is a great answer and completely answers my question! Thanks so much!